# How to check the rich results in Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, rich-snippets

Is there a report or a tool in Google Search Console that lets us check rich snippets for our site?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t trust Search Console as the sole source of authority on how your Rich Results are performing but this is a nice addition to see their value.

**You can find it in the new Search Console in:**

- Performance -> Search Appearance tab -> Rich Results line

If you don’t see the Search Appearance tab or the Rich Results listed, Search Console might not be detecting them yet or you might have found a Search Console bug. The prior version of Search Console had abysmal support for structured data and was wrong more often than right…

Most Shopify themes don’t quality for Google’s Rich Results so they lose out on these highly visible SEO enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

There's the Enhancements sidebar. It reports on certain types of structured data if it finds any. There you will find out what has been found, if it has errors or warnings and even a way to preview what they may look like.